# Listas enlazadas

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Buenas no entiendo porque no copila el programa además de eso no tengo idea de que cuanto tiene que mostrar las notas me de además el promedio de las notas y cual es la nota mayor y menor.

Lo de mostrar las notas de forma ordenada esta de mas no es necesario solo lo agregue por estética, y no se si estoy implementado bien las funciones en el código.

Además si se puede implementar mas mejoras les agradecería mucho.

```
struct nodo {
    int dato;
    nodo *siguiente;
}

void insertarLista(Nodo *& int );
void mostarLista(Nodo *);

int main() {
    nodo *lista = NULL;

    int dato;

    menu();

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void menu() {
    int opcion

    do {
        cout << "MENU: ";
        cout << "1. Insertar Nota ";
        cout << "2. Mostar Notas ";
        cout << "3. Salir ";
        cin >> opcion;

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                cout << "Ingrese Las Notas: ";
                cin >> dato;
                insertarLista(Lista, dato);
                cout << "\n";
                system("pause");
                break;
            case 2:
                MostarLista(lista);
                cout << "\n";
                system("pause");
                break;
        }
        system("cls");
    }
    while (opcion != 3);
}

void insertarLista(Nodo *&lista, int n) {
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
    nuevo_nodo->dato = n;

    Nodo *aux1 = lista;
    Nodo *aux2;

    while ((aux1 != NULL) && (aux1->dato < n)) {
        aux2 = aux1;
        aux1 = aux1->siguiente;
    }
    if (lista == aux1) {
        lista = nuevo_nodo;
    } else {
        aux2->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = aux1;
}

void mostrarLista(Nodo *lista) {
    Nodo *acual = new nodo();
    actual = lista;
    while (actual != NULL) {
        cout << actual->dato << " -> ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a mencionar las observaciones que encontré en tu código. Primero ten en cuenta en el orden que vas a estar estructurando tus funciones. Pongamos un ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
    menu(); // llamo a menu()
    return 0;
}

void menu() // defino a menu()
{
  //...
}
```

Cuando quieres llamar una función que está debajo, te soltará un error porque el código c++ lee el código de **arriba hacia abajo**, y en este caso lo primero que se está leyendo es la llamada de la función antes de que la función sea definida, de la cual no lo reconocerá aún. La solución de esto sería que primero el código lea a la función definida y posteriormente lo llamaras:

```
void menu() // defino a menu()
{
  //...
}

int main()
{
    menu(); // llamo a menu()
    return 0;
}
```

O también, puedes declarar a la función encima de tu `int main()` y debajo lo que contendrá la función, esto daría el mismo resultado:

```
void menu(); // defino a menu()

int main()
{
    menu(); // llamo a menu()
    return 0;
}

void menu() // menu() será esto
{
  //...
}
```

Ahora la siguiente observación es que tienes muchos errores de sintaxis:

- Te faltaron algunos `;` en tu código.
- Faltaban algunos cierres en las llaves.
- Se declaran variables inexistentes (mal escritas).

Respecto a la última observación, recuerda que c++ es [**`case-sensitive`**](https://www.quora.com/What-is-C-case-sensitive-What-does-that-mean), por ejemplo:

> `Nodo` es distinta a `nodo`. **|** `Opcion` es distinto a `opcion`.

Arreglando la sintaxis y observaciones en tu código, resultaría así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

struct nodo
{
    int dato;
    nodo *siguiente;
} *primero, *ultimo;

nodo *lista = NULL;

void insertarLista()
{
    nodo *nuevo_nodo = new nodo();

    cout << "Ingrese Las Notas: ";
    cin >> nuevo_nodo->dato;

    if (primero == NULL)
    {
        primero = nuevo_nodo;
        primero->siguiente = NULL;
        ultimo = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    else
    {
        ultimo->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
        nuevo_nodo->siguiente = NULL;
        ultimo = nuevo_nodo;
    }
}

void mostrarLista()
{
    nodo *actual = new nodo();
    actual = primero;
    if (primero != NULL)
    {
        while (actual != NULL)
        {
            cout << actual->dato << " -> ";
            actual = actual->siguiente;
        }
    }
}

void menu();

int main()
{
    menu();

    getch();
    return 0;
}


void menu()
{
    int opcion;
    int dato;

    do
    {
        cout << "MENU: \n";
        cout << "1. Insertar Nota \n";
        cout << "2. Mostar Notas \n";
        cout << "3. Salir \n";
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Ingrese una opcion: ";
        cin >> opcion;

        system("cls");

        switch (opcion)
        {
        case 1:
            insertarLista();
            cout << "\n";
            system("pause");
            break;

        case 2:
            mostrarLista();
            cout << "\n";
            system("pause");
            break;
        }
        system("cls");
    } while (opcion != 3);
}
```

**Output:**

```
// MENU: 
// 1. Insertar Nota    
// 2. Mostar Notas     
// 3. Salir 

// Ingrese una opcion: 1

// Ingrese Las Notas: 13
// Ingrese Las Notas: 14
// Ingrese Las Notas: 15

// 13 -> 14 -> 15 ->
```

Comment: gracias y para agregar que me muestre el promedio y la nota mayor y menor donde lo agrego

Comment: Recuerda verificar la respuesta si te sirvió para marcar como respondida tu pregunta. Claro, crearías la función encima de tu `int main()` y haces un `case` más.

Comment: Bien, pero la terminología no es exacta. En el tercer bloque de código dices `void menu(); // defino a menu()` pero esa línea no es una definición, es una mera declaración.

Answer (score 1):

El código tiene varios problemas.

- Al final de algunas instrucciones faltan `;`. Al cerrar la estructura `Nodo` y en la variable `opcion`.
- Los nombres de los símbolos son inconsistentes. En algunos sitios están en mayúsculas, en otros en minúsculas o incluso les falta una letra.
- Falta la declaración de la función `menu`.
- Falta una coma para separar los parámetros de la función `insertarLista`.
- Hay referencias a variables fuera de alcance:

  ```
  int main() {
      nodo *lista = NULL;
      int dato;

      ...
  }

  void menu() {
      int opcion;

      ...
          cout << "Ingrese Las Notas: ";
          cin >> dato;
          // dato está en la función main.
          insertarLista(Lista, dato);
          // Lista también.
      ...
  }
  ```
- En la función `mostrar` se crea un Nodo innecesariamente y la variable `actual` nunca cambia. Por lo tanto se produce un ciclo infinito.
- Puede que `getch` no esté disponible en todos los compiladores. Mejor usa `cin.get()`.
- Si tienes la posibilidad de reemplazar las funciones `system` por algo mejor, hazlo. Ya que solo funcionan con comandos de tu sistema operativo.

El código te podría quedar así:

```
struct Nodo {
    int dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

void insertarLista(Nodo *&, int);
void mostrarLista(Nodo *);
void menu();

int main() {
    menu();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void menu() {
    Nodo *lista = NULL;
    int opcion;
    int dato;

    do {
        cout << "MENU: ";
        cout << "1. Insertar Nota ";
        cout << "2. Mostar Notas ";
        cout << "3. Salir ";
        cin >> opcion;

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                cout << "Ingrese Las Notas: ";
                cin >> dato;
                insertarLista(lista, dato);
                cout << "\n";
                system("pause");
                break;
            case 2:
                mostrarLista(lista);
                cout << "\n";
                system("pause");
                break;
        }
        system("cls");
    }
    while (opcion != 3);
}

void insertarLista(Nodo *&lista, int n) {
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
    nuevo_nodo->dato = n;

    Nodo *aux1 = lista;
    Nodo *aux2;

    while ((aux1 != NULL) && (aux1->dato < n)) {
        aux2 = aux1;
        aux1 = aux1->siguiente;
    }
    if (lista == aux1) {
        lista = nuevo_nodo;
    } else {
        aux2->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = aux1;
}

void mostrarLista(Nodo *lista) {
    Nodo *actual = lista;
    while (actual != NULL) {
        cout << actual->dato << " -> ";
        actual = actual->siguiente;
    }
}
```

Comment: funciona pero al mostrar las notas me repite la ultima nota sin parar